# How to pass --autoscaling_algorithm=NONE flag to dataflow in python code?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am launching dataflow template using python dataflow.projects().templates().launch() function to launch dataflow job from jdbc to bigquery template.

How can i pass "--autoscaling_algorithm=NONE" flag inside this python function?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I verified in the backend log that the min_num_workers experiment is honored. When you launch a template, add following parameters to limit the job to run with N workers at all times.

- `"additionalExperiments": ["min_num_workers=N"]`
- `"maxWorkers": N`
- `"numWorkers": N`

---

I assume the goal is to disable autoscaling? You can achieve the same by setting `maxWorkers=1`.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/RuntimeEnvironment

Comment: maxWorkers will simply decide how many maximum workers can be created. But it'll not stop autoscaling.

Comment: @Dhairyaa Right, isn't that your goal though? --autoscaling_algorithm=NONE also disables autoscaling, so they both achieve the same. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#autoscaling

Comment: if I use maxWorkers=3,still my workers can be autooscaled to 2 or 1. As maxWorkers is the maximum number of workers that can be created. It does not disable autoscaling.

Comment: @Dhairyaa that is true. That's why I suggested to specify maxWorkers=1 (not 2 or 3). That way the pipeline starts with 1 worker and stays like that. Are you trying to keep more than one worker and disable autoscaling? If so, enabling autoscaling will save you money most of the time :) Another suggestion is setting minNumWorkers and maxWorkers as the same value, but I don't remember if minNumWorkers is supported with templates on top of my head.

Comment: minNumWorkers is not supported. and yes, i am trying to to keep more than one worker and disable autoscaling.

Comment: @Dhairyaa Can you try with `"additionalExperiments": ["minNumWorkers=4"]`, `"maxWorkers": 4`, and `"numWorkers": 4` ?

Comment: i checked dataflow job with "additionalExperiments": ["minNumWorkers=4"] parameter. still it deleted some workers after few time

Comment: @Dhairyaa I think it's `"additionalExperiments": ["min_num_workers=4"]` (not minNumWorkers). My streaming job has been running for 30 minutes without scaling down. If it doesn't work, then you probably have to hardcode it in your template as @aemon4 suggested.

Comment: @Dhairyaa 1 hr+, and still didn't downscale :)

Comment: Hey , I'll try this parameter :)

Answer (score 0):

To disable autoscaling within the python function itself use `autoscaling_algorithm=None` in the [PipelineOptions](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.4.0/apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.html). For example:

```py
p = beam.Pipeline(argv=beam_args,options=PipelineOptions(
region='us-central1',autoscaling_algorithm=None,num_workers=2))
```

or in more detail, following the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#configuring-pipelineoptions-for-execution-on-the-cloud-dataflow-service):

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

options = PipelineOptions(
    flags=argv,
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project='my-project-id',
    job_name='unique-job-name',
    temp_location='gs://my-bucket/temp',
    region='us-central1',
    autoscaling_algorithm=None,
    num_workers=2)

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
# build your pipeline here.
```

If you create a streaming job with python3 you may need to include the experiments flag `disable_streaming_engine` as it has autoscaling enabled by default and it overrides the manually set flag. I've created a job with those options and after 10min of no interaction it still remained in 2 workers so it seems to be working properly.